# How can I forbid the user to use chrome devtool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In some cases, I don't want someone debug my code with devtool. At present, my plan is to disable the combination button, but I can't catch the action after right-click event, What should I do then?

```
document.onkeydown = (e) => {
      let condition_one = e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && ['i', 'I'].includes(e.key),
        condition_two = ['F12', 'f12'].includes(e.key);

      if (condition_one || condition_two) {
        setInterval(() => {
          debugger;
        })
      }
}
```

Comment: what would prevent someone from modifying your code?

Comment: You can't the user can open the context menu and then select open dev tools

Comment: this is indeed a good question, but try more of your self-research before asking answers.

Comment: The only way to minimize your source code exposure is to handle everything you can server side with PHP or NodeJS for example and just push the results to your front end. At least that way you'll only expose your structure, design and end result data. Nothing else

Comment: You should ask yourself *why* you don't want users to see your code. Whatever it is you don't want the user to see/modify, put that on the server-side instead. The user can *always* find a way to see and modify the frontend code. Sensitive data should not be sent to the frontend.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson You can send sensitive data to the front end if you want (and have SSL of course). Just don't rely on it server side. I mean, someone's private address data often must be sent to the front end and is clearly sensitive data. Same goes for a username. But obviously you don't simply rely on the username for identification. Otherwise the user could just edit it and pretend to be whoever they want to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that. You can make it harder by preventing the context menu and overwrite f12 hotkey, but they can still just open the browser settings and open it there.

They can also just navigate to your website with the devtools already open.

Comment: Not to mention that it's client side code, hence the browser _must_ download it in order to show it. It wouldn't be too hard to search your internet cache by filtering on date and get it there

Comment: @icecub or just download the file directly, from the url.